# Django login part

Tags: python, django

I am now working on a system using the Django framework. I am writing the user login part. It seems successful but it doesn't work very well.

- The login system can recognise the user by his/her username and password.
- The authentication could only last for one "webpage". When I loaded another page or even reloaded the page, django can't get the info of the user(seems logged out)
- If I looked at the page resources, I saw a session number made after the login process.

What should I do to ensure only one login is needed? And keep my user logged in during the whole process?

Here is my view file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response,redirect
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.template.context_processors import csrf
from . import models
from . import form as f
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore

def index(request):
    if request.user != None :
        template = loader.get_template('index.html')
        return HttpResponse(template.render(None))
    else :
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/PDT/login_failed')

def Home(request):
    template = loader.get_template('Home.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(None))  

def loggin_in(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('login.html', c)

def login_user(request):
    logout(request)
    username = password = ''
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST.get('username','')
        password = request.POST.get('password','')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                request.session['username']=user.username



                return HttpResponseRedirect('/PDT/logged_successful')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/PDT/inactive')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/PDT/incorrect')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/PDT/login_failed')

def logged_in(request):
    if request.user :
        return render_to_response('index.html',{ 'user' : request.user },context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else :
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/PDT/login_failed')

def login_failed(request):
    return render_to_response('problem.html',{ 'message' : "Login failed" })

def log_out(request):
    request.session.flush()
    logout(request)
    return render_to_response('problem.html',{ 'message' : "Logged out" })

def inactive(request):
    return render_to_response('problem.html',{ 'message' : "Inactive" })

def incorrect(request):
    return render_to_response('problem.html',{ 'message' : "Incorrect Username or Password" })

def iter_update(request):
    if request.session['username'] != None :
        return render_to_response('iter_update.html',{ 'user' : request.user },context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else :
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/PDT/login_failed')

def Create_form(request):
    if request.method == "POST":

        form = f.ProjectForm(request.POST)

        if(form.is_valid()):
            print(request.POST['title'])
            form.save()
            message = 'success'
        else:
            message = 'fail'

        return render_to_response('Create_form.html',
              {'message': message,
              'user': request.user,},
              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return render_to_response('Create_form.html',
                {'form': f.ProjectForm()},
                context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Please add the relevant settings from your settings file. For authentication to work, you need to have at least the settings as [outlined in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/#installation). In that case, the currently logged in user is available via `request.user` automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use `return render(request, template_name, context_dict)` to render templates. Your peculiar way probably strips it of context.

Also, [take a look at this decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator), and use it instead of your current `if request.user != None :` statements.

Answer (score 2):

Your user *is* logged in, but because you are strangely rendering the Home and Index templates via template.render(None), there is no `request` or `user` context in your template. Instead, use the `render` shortcut which runs context processors.